# Synchronous HTTP Requests in C++

Tags: c++, http, synchronous, unreal-engine4

I have set up a multiplayer dedicated server that runs using PHP scripts and MySQL databases. I am trying to access the server via HTTP to send/receive game data, starting with something as simple as getting the server status.

I have been able to contact the server successfully using the Unreal Doc's IHttpRequest:

```
void ANetwork::getContentsOfURL(FString URL)
{
    serverResponse = NULL;

    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest> HttpRequest = FHttpModule::Get().CreateRequest();
    HttpRequest->SetHeader(TEXT("Content-Type"), TEXT("application/json"));
    HttpRequest->SetURL(URL);
    HttpRequest->SetVerb(TEXT("POST"));

    //Creating JSON Object
    FString json = "{\"auth\":\"" + authenticator = "\"";

    json += "}";

    HttpRequest->SetContentAsString(json);
    HttpRequest->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(this, &ANetwork::OnResponseReceived);
    HttpRequest->ProcessRequest();
}

void ANetwork::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful)
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Red, Response->GetContentAsString());

    if (!Response.IsValid())
    {
        serverResponse = "FAIL";
    }
    else
    {
        serverResponse = Response->GetContentAsString();
    }
}
```

And this echoes the proper codes to the debugger, so I know the server is working and the code is in fact getting what it needs to get. However, I need to be able to get the HTTP response as an FString and return it to the caller so that I can use it in-game. Right now this method is asynchronous, which prevents me from returning the response.

How can I make a synchronous HTTP Request so that I can return the response as a string to the caller?

i.e.

```
FString ANetwork::getContentsOfURL(FString URL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset (unsignal) an event at the bottom of getContentsOfUrl. 
Await for it to become signaled. 
Signal the event from OnResponseReceived.

CreateEvent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx ResetEvent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685081(v=vs.85).aspx WaitForSingleObject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx SetEvent (signals it) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686211(v=vs.85).aspx

```
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

// bottom getCongentsOfUrl:
ResetEvent(hEvent); // optional because inital state is unsignaled
WaitForSingleObject(hEvent);

// OnResponseReceived
SetEvent(hEvent)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate just a bit. I'm pretty green in C++. How do I "signal" and "unsignal" the event?

Comment: It's looking good so far. It compiled :) Let me test it real quick.

Comment: One problem that I'm seeing is that I have to specify how long to wait for the event. Ideally, the wait would simply end when the event was set.

Comment: I got it to work! I used a similar idea, but with a while loop: `bool wait = true;
 while (wait)
 {
  if (HttpRequest->GetResponse()->GetContentAsString() != "")
  {
   return HttpRequest->GetResponse()->GetContentAsString();
  }
 }` Thanks so much for your help!